# Facing These Issues When Generating IOS Build

Tags: ios, flutter, tensorflow, build, tensorflow2.0

These are the Errors while generating  The IOS build

[TFlite Error (2.7.0) This is the current package which I am  using in my project
The Tflite Issue has been resolved when I downgrade my TenserFlowliteC (2.7.0)  to  enserFlowliteC (2.2.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB89I.jpg)

While Resolving the TenserFlowLiteC error following errors occurs:-
[->Command EmitSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code ( Errors cause due to TenserFlowLiteC library)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3GMT.png)

[->No such module 'Flutter' ( Errors cause due to TenserFlowLiteC library)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy9MU.jpg)